# SSRS different results in Data tab and Preview tab

Tags: reporting-services

I get the correct results (nov and dec data) when I run a query in the Data tab of a report that I built in SQL Server Reporting Services.  When I preview the report I get old data from October.  It doesn't make any sense to me. I'm not sure whats going on. Note: the data is in Oracle.

Here's the date filter I'm using

```
receipt_date + 2 <= SYSDATE
```

The query works fine in SQL Developer and in the Data tab in the .rdl designer in Visual Studio... just not in the Preview tab when I run the report... that's when I get Oct. data.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 24):

SSRS caches data locally for use by the designer.  The cached data is only updated if the developer previews the report in VS.NET using a different set of parameters, which in your case never happens because the report has no parameters.

To allow SSRS to refresh the cached data, navigate to the directory which contains your design-time RDL file and delete any files which have the extension ".data".

Answer (score 10):

This is way too late, but maybe this can help someone else in the future.

When developing SQL Reporting Services reports, a really annoying function is that preview data is cached locally when testing reports instead of fetched on every run. Even explicitly refreshing the data doesn't always fix this. The most reliable way to resolve this is to delete the .data file associated with your report RDL file. These data files are stored in the same folder with your report definitions.

While you can delete these files manually, the following 15 second configuration change to BIS makes the process of deleting all data caches as simple as a menu selection.

Let's see how to achieve this.

In Visual Studio -->

1. Go to Tools - External Tools...
2. Add a new tool with the following settings:

[image]

Now whenever you want to delete your report data cache, just go to Tools - Clear Report Data Cache.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that works for me (in 2008 R2) is deleting the .data file and rebuilding the report.  The **refresh button on the preview tab does nothing** nor does editing the RSReportDesigner.config file (located in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies*).  Very frustrating.  If I change the query or sp logic I now have to manually delete the .data file in the report project directory in order to see the the most recent rendering of the data.

Hope this was fixed in SSRS 2012 data tools.

Answer (score 1):

see the links 
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/522670/ssrs-turn-off-local-data-cache-in-bids#

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/145ac9ac-b247-47d2-a787-98a8fcfad053

Answer (score 1):

The link in Greg's post points to this workaround, added after Greg posted: http://blog.summitcloud.com/2010/05/disable-reporting-services-data-cache-in-development/ That explains which config file controls the data caching, and says that refreshing the preview may actually get you fresh data. (I'm running a long query now, so I don't know yet if that works.)

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting the Refresh button on the Preview tab.

If I understand properly, that is the same issue I had with mine.

I could see the query run successfully in the Report Data window but whenever I ran the Preview of the report, I was getting no results.

I realised after a bit of mucking around, all I needed to do was hit the Refresh button (mini icons on the the Preview tab) to get the Preview refreshed with the new data.

Comment: Pressing the refresh button in BIDS VS2010 for me isn't working. Nor did deleting the cache file. Something more bizarre is going on - I've verified the data coming from the stored procedure. The RDL comes from a 2008 solution copy, so perhaps it's bugged here.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything different regarding the dataset's parameters? Do report parameters feed the dataset at all? If so what are they?
Is the report a server report? If so what is the time set to on the server?

Answer (score 0):

There are no report parameters.....the exact same sql is run everytime.  I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if the report is a server report.

Answer (score 0):

i have one theory that i haven't been able to test.  this report is not deployed to Report Manager but is being run from Visual Studio.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the refresh button in BIDS VS2010 for me isn't working. Nor did deleting the cache file. My issue was that I didn't have a Row Group - so it was only showing one (old) record on  the report.